# How can get list Members of web host from addins?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin

I want get list group member of sites and email of users of groups from my addins:

[image]

I had tried this code but, it can't: it showing error `testsite Members is not exist`

```
function loadcboGroupofSite() {
    var hostWebContext = new SP.AppContextSite(clientContext, hostWebURL);
    var listStatus = hostWebContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('testsite Members');
    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
    var Items = listStatus.getItems(camlQuery);
    clientContext.load(Items, 'Include(Title, Id)');
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, function (data) {
        var listItemInfo = "<option>All</option>";
        // Iterate through Enumerator
        var oEnumerator = Items.getEnumerator();

        while (oEnumerator.moveNext()) {
            
         
            var title = oEnumerator.get_current().get_item('Title');       
          
            listItemInfo += '<option>' + title + '</option>';          
        }
    
        $("#cboGroup").html(listItemInfo);

    }), Function.createDelegate(this, function (sender, args) {
        alert('request failed ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());

    }));
}
```

How can get list Members of web host from addins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code `hostWebContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('testsite Members');` is to get a list instead of get a group. To get a group in the web, you need to use [SP.Web.siteGroups property](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-visio/jj246603(v=office.15)).

Change your code to the following:

```
var group = hostWebContext.get_web().get_siteGroups().getByName('testsite Members');
var users = group.get_users();
clientContext.load(users);
clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, function (data) {
    var listItemInfo = "<option>All</option>";
    // Iterate through Enumerator
    var oEnumerator = users.getEnumerator();

    while (oEnumerator.moveNext()) {


        var title = oEnumerator.get_current().get_title();
        console.log(title);
        listItemInfo += '<option>' + title + '</option>';
    }
```

Comment: thank you very much.

Comment: You are welcome :)